# Laravel app inside Wordpress website run on app folder and not in app/public folder?

Tags: laravel, wordpress, directory, root, public

I have a wordpress website in which I want to use a Laravel app in a subfolder

Like this:

- https://website.com/* -> wordpress
- https://website.com/app/ -> laravel

But I only managed to run it like this:

- https://website.com/* -> wordpress
- https://website.com/app/ -> http 404
- https://website.com/app/public/ -> laravel

Whatever I do, I keep receiving http 404 when trying to access any of my views except when trying on the public folder.

What can I do to make laravel start routing from the root laravell app (/app, like normally is when it's only laravel) and not from the /app/public folder?

I have tried changing RewriteBase but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do this using a subdomain, but anyway

- Create a folder with the desired name inside the cPanel public_html
  folder, for example, **Laravel**
- Put the contents of the public folder related to Laravel into this
  folder
- Create another folder with the name **app** or any other desired name in
  cPanel and before the Public_html folder and put the complete content
  of Laravel except the **Public** folder into this folder.

[image]

- Now go to the public_html folder and then enter the Laravel folder
  and open the index.php file and apply the following changes and save
  the file:
- 

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/vendor/autoload.php';
$maintenance = __DIR__.'/../app/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Update the `.env` file according to the database information and then open the address of your Laravel program

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I did that but the app now is running on /app/public/Laravel

Did I do something wrong or there's something more I need to do?